# Can DbModelStore works with last version of EF 6.x?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, caching, query-performance

I'm currently working with EF 6.1.3 version and I've tried to use the Nuget Package EntityFrameworkDbModelStore but unfortunately the package is builded with EF 6.0.0.

Can someone help me to find a solution for my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: this semas to be a fork of the original EF6.1.3. Simply install it and see what happens

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you for help Me, I try to do it

Comment: I've downloaded the current version of source code of EF (6.1.3) but when I build the project the assembly file version still remains 6.1.0 and I cannot use it in my solution...

Comment: i never used this lib so I can't help

Comment: Mattia, you might need to sign the built EF libraries with an own key (strong named assemblies) and change the fingerprint in your project files using it to the resulting fingerprint.